# tableless form layout that handles internationalization

Tags: html, forms, layout, css

Pretty simple one here. Well ... simple to ask - not so much to answer.

It seems most tableless form layouts require setting the width of the label to a set width to allow all the input elements to align on the right. e.g. http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms/

Problem I'm having is that the application I'm building has to allow for internationalization - where a user can click on a link and change the locale to somewhere else, and subsequently the text in all the labels changes to something else.

So, for example, in a table based form layout you have 2 columns - one for labels, one for input elements. All the input elements are aligned left and thus line up down all the rows. It's very easy to set up such that the width of the label column is equal to the widest possible label.

However with tableless layouts for forms the labels all must have a set width to align the input elements. You can't set them to all be as wide as the widest label easily.

I'm after a fix that doesn't involve:

just set the label to be as wide as the widest word in all the
   possible languages

programatically set the width of the style associated with the labels
   after the page is rendered.

Basically I want what a table based layout would do. If that's possible. Without tables.

Thanks.

Comment: take alook and see if this helps any http://jsfiddle.net/nalagg/yBWmf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve that is to simulate tables in CSS, i.e. to set `display: table` etc. This will not work on IE 7 and earlier. I suggest that you reconsider the reasons for rejecting table markup for tabular data like a typical form.

Comment: Delayed reaction sorry ... but this answer proved very useful. I now have a full system using CSS tables.

About the only drawback that I've found so far is that colspan still isn't supported is CSS tables. I've made a workaround (read:hack) but overall very happy with CSS tables and how they handle constantly changing label widths.